# PHP - Сортировка массива по возрасту

Tags: php

Есть такой массив:

```
<?php
$entries=array();
$entries[0]["displayname"]="Ivan"  ;
$entries[0]["age"]=32              ;
$entries[1]["displayname"]="Anna"  ;
$entries[1]["age"]=24              ;
$entries[2]["displayname"]="Bob"   ;
$entries[2]["age"]=29              ;
$entries[3]["displayname"]="Stuart";
$entries[3]["age"]=28              ;

For ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {echo $entries[$i]["displayname"] .' '. $entries[$i]["age"].'<br>';}
?>
```

Как сделать сортировку массива по возрасту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

до php7:

```
usort($entries,function($a,$b) { 
    if ($a['age'] == $b['age']) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $a['age'] > $b['age'];
    }
});
```

php7:

```
usort($entries,function($a,$b) { 
    return $a['age'] <=> $b['age'];
});
```

это сортировка от меньшего к большему. если нужно наоборот - поменяйте в функции $a и $b местами.

Comment: гениально. да здравствует php 7.  этого не хватало.

Comment: до пхп 7 все пишут `retun $a['age'] - $b['age'];` а не то что вы.

Comment: @teran, ну я же не сам это придумал. из [мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) стащил, первый пример)

Comment: если успею сам до того как мне тут ответ дадут то тоже хорошо :)

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko а чем первый вариант не подошел?

Comment: первый вариант отлично работает. но надо добавить сортировку по имени после сортировки по возрасту.

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko, выделите весь блок if-else, скопируйте его, подставьте его вместо `return 0;` и в этом конкретном блоке замените 'age' на 'name'. получите двойную сортировку.